# UWP TreeView crash

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, treeview, win-universal-app

I have a `TreeView` (I almost copied the same code from XAML Controls Gallary):

```
    <TreeView
        x:Name="LocalFolderTreeView"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource FolderTreeTemplateSelector}"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Tree, Mode=OneWay}"
        Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

And the XAML of `ItemTemplateSelector`:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FolderTemplate" x:DataType="data:FolderTree">
        <TreeViewItem
            DoubleTapped="FolderTreeItem_DoubleTapped"
            IsDoubleTapEnabled="True"
            IsExpanded="False"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Files}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel.ContextFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyout Opening="OpenPlaylistFlyout" />
                </StackPanel.ContextFlyout>
                <SymbolIcon Symbol="Folder" />
                <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Path}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="FileTemplate" x:DataType="data:Music">
        <TreeViewItem>
            <StackPanel
                DoubleTapped="FileItem_DoubleTapped"
                IsDoubleTapEnabled="True"
                Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel.ContextFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyout Opening="OpenMusicFlyout" />
                </StackPanel.ContextFlyout>
                <Image Width="20" Source="Assets/colorful_no_bg.png" />
                <TextBlock Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>

    <templateselector:FolderTreeTemplateSelector
        x:Key="FolderTreeTemplateSelector"
        FileTemplate="{StaticResource FileTemplate}"
        FolderTemplate="{StaticResource FolderTemplate}" />
```

C# of `ItemTemplateSelector` is

```
public class FolderTreeTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate FolderTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate FileTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is Models.FolderTree) return FolderTemplate;
        if (item is Models.Music) return FileTemplate;
        return null;
    }
}
```

It is used [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/LocalFoldersPage.xaml)

My ViewModels are defined [here](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/tree/master/SMPlayer/Models).

When I add this to the `TreeView`, my app crashes. `Tree` is not null because I also defined `GridView` that allows me to see it.

```
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Tree, Mode=OneWay}"
```

What is wrong?

Comment: I checked `LocalFoldersPage`, I can't find you have set the itemsource for the TreeView. So, I'm not sure the data structure is matched with your xaml.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I removed it because it caused my app to crash. You can add it back.

Comment: How can I navigate LocalFoldersPage ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT You need a folder that contains a folder of music files. Basically set `folder1` to be your root path if you have music file like `folder1/folder2/music.mp3`.

Comment: I check the FolderTree it's not matched actual folder structure.

Comment: It is a simplified version of that. But I care more about why my app crashes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199819/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-seaky-luo).

Comment: I think the wrong data source structure cause this issue.

Comment: Please check `TreeView` ItemsSource, it looks not a collection.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `ItemsSource` is collection type， but in above code the **Tree** data source is `FolderTree`, it will cause argument error, please modify it as collection base on your actual data structure.